# React ReactCSSTransitionGroup adding and animating new item to top of list?

Tags: animation, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have been looking around for an example of adding items to a list with react and having it animate the newly added item, but not to the end of the list, but the beginning of the list. I found this example, but all the messing around I have done locally and online, I cant seem to get the item to animate when added to the first spot in the array. Here is a simple react todo add item. How can I get the item to add to the first spot, and do the animation to the first spot?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/13152/

```jsx
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

var TodoList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {items: ['hello', 'world', 'click', 'me']};
  },
  handleAdd: function() {
    var newItems =
      this.state.items.concat([prompt('Enter some text')]);
    this.setState({items: newItems});
  },
  handleRemove: function(i) {
    var newItems = this.state.items;
    newItems.splice(i, 1)
    this.setState({items: newItems});
  },
  render: function() {
    var items = this.state.items.map(function(item, i) {
      return (
        <TodoItem item={item} key={item} onClick={this.handleRemove.bind(this,     i)}/>
      );
    }.bind(this));
    return (
      <div>
        <div><button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add new</button></div>
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
          {items}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<TodoList/>, document.getElementById('list'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is your appending to your todo list. If you add to the front, the resulting animation is what you are looking for.

Change the `handleAdd` to:

```js
handleAdd: function() {
  var newItems = this.state.items;
  newItems.unshift([prompt('Enter some text')]);
  this.setState({items: newItems});
},
```

the key point is to use `unshift` instead of `push`. Browse the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to understand the differences

Comment: I do this and the array is added as you want it at the beginning but the transition still happens at the last item as in if you have `['1', '2', '3']` and you  `unshift('0')` it will add at the start the `0` but the `3` is the one that will have the transition effect, always.